# Custom header, not using fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer

I want to add the following header to my chapters:

[image]

I do not want to use fancyhdr because when I use it, it moves all my previous page settings (principally the table of contents layout), I tried using /thispagestyle{fancy} but it does not work.

My code looks as follows:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,oneside,onecolumn,final,openany]{report}

\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{times}                   
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{apalike}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[left=2.7cm,top=2.5cm,right=2.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\hfill\rule{.7\textwidth}{3pt} \hspace*{.3\textwidth} \\ \hspace*{.3\textwidth} Contenido}}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\hfill\rule{.7\textwidth}{3pt} \hspace*{.3\textwidth} \\ \hspace*{.3\textwidth} Lista de Figuras}}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\listtablename}{\hfill\rule{.7\textwidth}{3pt} \hspace*{.3\textwidth} \\ \hspace*{.3\textwidth} Lista de Tablas}}

\pagestyle{myheadings}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\listoffigures
\clearpage
\listoftables
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\thispagestyle{myheadings}

\chapter{Introduction}
\label{chap:intro}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam convallis accumsan tempor. Etiam adipiscing gravida sollicitudin. Suspendisse potenti. Donec risus lectus, ultricies at varius in, accumsan quis sapien. Duis at arcu turpis, lacinia dapibus orci. Etiam pharetra turpis et diam volutpat in dapibus lorem facilisis. Vestibulum adipiscing, metus quis scelerisque pulvinar, purus quam iaculis felis, ac porta nulla justo nec dui. Donec condimentum pulvinar augue, varius placerat quam pharetra in. Vestibulum velit ante, feugiat imperdiet scelerisque in, posuere eu purus.

\section{Lorem ipsum}
\label{sec:intro:lorem}

Pellentesque sit amet dui non nunc venenatis tempus vel id libero. Etiam consectetur metus fringilla nibh 

\subsection{Ipsum}
\label{sec:intro:ipsum}

Etiam iaculis ante vitae diam egestas egestas. Nullam sed odio id mi consequat porttitor. Ut ut libero augue, 

\chapter{Things 2}
\label{chap:intro2}

\subsection{Pallentesque}
\label{sec:intro:pallen}

Pellentesque sit amet dui non nunc venenatis tempus vel id libero. Etiam consectetur metus fringilla nibh 

\end{document}
```

Currently it looks like this:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: add \pagestyle{myheadings}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I do not want to use fancyhdr because when I use it, it moves all my
>   previous page settings (principally the table of contents layout),

You can use `fancyhdr` without any worries and that is the easiest way out. Look at the following code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,oneside,onecolumn,final,openany]{report}

\usepackage{alltt,fancyhdr}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{apalike}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[left=2.7cm,top=2.5cm,right=2.2cm,bottom=2.5cm,headsep=.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\hfill\rule{.7\textwidth}{3pt} \hspace*{.3\textwidth} \\ \hspace*{.3\textwidth} Contenido}}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\hfill\rule{.7\textwidth}{3pt} \hspace*{.3\textwidth} \\ \hspace*{.3\textwidth} Lista de Figuras}}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\listtablename}{\hfill\rule{.7\textwidth}{3pt} \hspace*{.3\textwidth} \\ \hspace*{.3\textwidth} Lista de Tablas}}

\fancypagestyle{myheadings}{%
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[L]{\bfseries\itshape\nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\bfseries\nouppercase\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{15pt}
}
\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\listoffigures
\clearpage
\listoftables
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\pagestyle{myheadings}

\chapter{Introduction}
\label{chap:intro}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam convallis accumsan tempor. Etiam adipiscing gravida sollicitudin. Suspendisse potenti. Donec risus lectus, ultricies at varius in, accumsan quis sapien. Duis at arcu turpis, lacinia dapibus orci. Etiam pharetra turpis et diam volutpat in dapibus lorem facilisis. Vestibulum adipiscing, metus quis scelerisque pulvinar, purus quam iaculis felis, ac porta nulla justo nec dui. Donec condimentum pulvinar augue, varius placerat quam pharetra in. Vestibulum velit ante, feugiat imperdiet scelerisque in, posuere eu purus.

\section{Lorem ipsum}
\label{sec:intro:lorem}

Pellentesque sit amet dui non nunc venenatis tempus vel id libero. Etiam consectetur metus fringilla nibh
\clearpage

\subsection{Ipsum}
\label{sec:intro:ipsum1}

Etiam iaculis ante vitae diam egestas egestas. Nullam sed odio id mi consequat porttitor. Ut ut libero augue,
\clearpage
\subsection{Ipsum}
\label{sec:intro:ipsum2}

Etiam iaculis ante vitae diam egestas egestas. Nullam sed odio id mi consequat porttitor. Ut ut libero augue,

\chapter{Things 2}
\label{chap:intro2}

\subsection{Pallentesque}
\label{sec:intro:pallen}

Pellentesque sit amet dui non nunc venenatis tempus vel id libero. Etiam consectetur metus fringilla nibh

\end{document}
```

[image]

**You can see that the TOC layout is untouched.**

**Note** Instead of outdated `times` you must be using `mathptmx`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to achieve, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If the problem is with the height of the header when you use the `fancyhdr` package, remember that you can redefine the height of the header with the `geometry` package:

```
\usepackage[head=30pt,foot=...]{geometry}
```

You can play with this height and the whole page layout to minimize the impact of using `fancyhdr`.

Comment: You can load `geometry` with the option `showframe` in order to see the changes.